# Is it possible to use oracle sql functions with in command parameters

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I have a timestamp column which i want to setup using Systime. I am unable to understand how can I do that

getXYZCmd.Parameters.Add("myTimeStamp", ????).Value = {Oracle Systime};

I know I can do this via trigger, but just curious if it can be done via server side function

regards

Comment: There are two functions without params in Oracle: systimestamp - server timestamp, current_timestamp - session timestamp. You can try to use one of them in your sql statement

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your comment. But how do I set it in via Parameters. Any example will be great.